# Where can I find third party library source in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is my global build.gradle file's content:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

For example,
I add this line in my application module build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
```

where can I find okhttp.jar or something else in my mac ?

Comment: I found another way to find gradle cache or library source in Android Studio, and commit an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine it's under

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/
```

might be slightly different on your computer I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found these files in this place. And I realize I shouldn't care about these files, just declares libs what I need in the build.gradle.That's enough :)

Comment: Glad it helped you! Please don't forget to accept one of the answers if you feel your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find gradle cache in **Android Studio**.

Find this directory in your Android Studio's Project Tool windows:

[External Libraries screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbtai.png)

And find a repository you want, and right-click it, choose **Library Properties**, and you'll find the gradle cache directory in your mac.
[Library Properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCgyi.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default Gradle cache is located under your user home directory, in `.gradle/caches/`.

[Here are more details about it (inc how to override it)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_cache).

Comment: Thanks for editing my title! And I found files what I need in the directory you gave me :)